# How to consume a high volume topic as KTABLE without exhausting memory/disk space?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

We have a kstreams app doing kstream-kstable inner join. Both the topics are high volume with 256 partitions each. kstreams App is deployed on 8 nodes with 8 GB heap each right now.
The state store (rocksdb) persists to disk and we are running out of disk space on the containers. What are some of the options to consume data from one of the topics as  KTABLE, but limit the amount of data (like if we want to hold only a days worth of keys/data or some time frame) on disk and have the previous state/files get deleted?

Comment: You can try and make the backing topics `cleanup.policy=delete,compact` if you only want recent data

Comment: will that also delete the data persisted by the state store related to the ktable  on disk?

Comment: Not completely sure. My assumption would be no

Comment: okay, so thats where I am confused, not sure what happens to the data thats not relevant anymore after its spilled to disk as part of the state store.

Comment: may be I have to  consider consuming as stream and join with windowing instead of reading one of the topics as ktable , assuming windowing would work for my use case